# How to unclose modal when click on outside from js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am opening my modal from js and i want to unclose it when clicked on outside and I tried the following code but didnt worked.Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

```
  $('#login-register-model').modal({backdrop: 'static',keyboard: false}, 'show');
```

Comment: <div id="modal" class="modal hide fade in" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static"> will do a trick

Comment: $('#myModal').modal({  backdrop: 'static'; }); is solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="modal" class="modal hide fade in" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
```

will do a trick

Comment: for bootstrap 5 it's data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false"

Answer (score 0):

Need to restructure the call.

```
$('#login-register-model').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/athulnair/8crjw2en/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$('#login-register-model').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I this example. It's working properly with `backdrop: 'static'` property.

Please compare your code with this example might you missed something.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.launch-modal').click(function(){
  $('#myModal').modal({
   backdrop: 'static'
  });
 }); 
});
```

```css
.bs-example{
    margin: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="bs-example">
    <!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary launch-modal" value="Launch Demo Modal">
    
    <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Test</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Lorem Ipsum
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```